# Adding A record to DNS in WHM's Zone Editor?

Tags: dns, whm

I'm  trying to add a subdomain to my site and I'm not sure if my formatting is correct. I'm using WHM through cPanel, using the tool called "Edit Zone Templates".

Here's what I'm using now (a bit of context has been included):

```
localhost.%domain%. IN A 127.0.0.1

%domain%. IN MX 0 %domain%.

mail IN CNAME %domain%.
www IN CNAME %domain%.
ftp IN CNAME %domain%.
subdomain.%domain%. IN A 162.162.162.162
```

The last line is my addition (example IP used).

It takes a while to propagate, so I'd rather find a solution than keep trying new solutions and waiting a day to see if it worked properly.

If doesn't work, maybe it's

```
subdomain IN A 162.162.162.162
```

I don't know really know

Comment: I see a close request. I think this is on the same lines as `.htaccess` questions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It turns out WHM uses a standard DNS zone file.

So, the answer should be:

```
subdomain IN A 162.162.162.162
```

Here's a source:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file